# Adding Operand And to phase prefix query type in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I am new to elastic search. Operator 'AND' is working with 'cross fields' and 'best fields' query types but in match prefix it is not working, any suggestions how to make it work

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you be more specific, provide same document, mapping and your query

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html, did you try by using "operator" : "and" ?

Comment: try to be more specific.